# How to Remove SQLite3 from Rails but keep using ActiveRecord/Mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I have made a Rails project that will use Mongo, I already installed MongoDb and its using it. 
But the project is requiring to use SQLite3. I can’t find any recommendations on how to remove it without removing ActiveRecord or making a new project .

How should I remove SQLit3 without removing ActiveRecord in order to keep using Mongo?

---

**update**
This have been very difficult. 
The app is still crashing and complaining about the ActiveRecord dependencies.
I found that is easier to make a clean install if RoR without database

```
Rails new MyApp -O
```

Then install Mongo, and it works fine.

```
gem 'mongoid'
rails g mongoid:config
```

Also to the same to build an Rspec based app, its better to make the app without the Test section and the add Rspec. 
So the solution was to go on a clean install

```
rails new MyApp -O -T
```

then instal rspec...

My problem is that I already have an app and can’t find an easy way to clean it from SQLite3, so I guess it’s better to migrate the code to a new clean app??

Comment: Why do you want to keep ActiveRecord? ActiveRecord doesn't support mongo

Comment: I cant find an answer, but for the future the recomendation is to start a clean project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0RqU2MdqXU&list=PL4XBVtvKZKqdV61wCONUnUopE0NzwCfU3&index=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Gemfile` will have the line

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Remove it and run `bundle install`.

Also, change the configuration in your `config/database.yml`, it might still be using SQLite3. If there is the below line in `database.yml`, it means it is trying to use SQLite3:

```
adapter: splite3
```

Change it to match the MongoDB configuration.

This will remove SQLite3 requirement for your rails app. However, you need to know that this won't delete the database that was already create in SQLite3 by the rails app, you will have to delete that manually.

Comment: Thanks Sri, I tried this, but I get stuck later when I try to do anything and it complains that I need SQLite3, do you have an idea of what do I have to delete from the project to remove the ActiveRecord/SQLite3 code? Rails is asking me to reinstall the gem.

Comment: There might be some configuration in the `database.yml` that uses SQLite3. I updated my answer to consider that too.

Comment: Sorry still crashing. I guess I need to start clean.  :(